# Reload tab view after goBack routing (Ionic 4)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, routes, tabs

I need navigate from my tab to another component using navigateForward (navController), and make api call on that page. After that i need to use goBack function, route to my component and get data there, but i can't because my page don't reload, and my method ionViewWillEnter don't call, so i can't update my data.
Can anyone have an answer for it question?